# function return not wait for timer stop

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, timer

I create function in which I create System.Timers.Timer and in new thread new function is invoke. But my first function not wait for timer.Stop execution and return value after invoke timer.Start()

When I add this code before function return:

```
while(timer.Enabled)
{
Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

timer function is never invoked :/

Wwhat I do wrong ?

Comment: Use System.Threading.Timer class. This class utilizes Thread Pool.

Comment: My timer should be from this class? And then Thread Sleep will work ?

Comment: Yes. System.Timers.Timer fires on UI thread only. This does not use Thread Pool. Try using Timer from System.Threading.Timer and your code should work.

Comment: @jags - your comment is not correct.  System.Timers.Timer works in a multithreaded environment, albeit you are correct about System.Threading.Timer.  The problem is there are 3 different timers.

Comment: Actually, `System.Timers.Timer` is a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. If you set the `SynchronizingObject` property in `System.Timers.Timer` to the form, the event will be raised on the UI thread. Otherwise it will be raised on a threadpool thread.

Comment: You will have to show more code if you want an answer. Your description is inadequate for us to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the MSDN documentation, you would see the following note (I suspect this is what is going on, but without additional code it is impossible to tell):

> The event-handling method might run on one thread at the same time
>   that another thread calls the Stop method or sets the Enabled property
>   to false. This might result in the Elapsed event being raised after
>   the timer is stopped. The example code for the Stop method shows one
>   way to avoid this race condition.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx